# How to test bluetooth android to pc (non bluetooth)?

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

Since in bluetooth programming we need 2 important things **UUID** and **Mac Address**.

Would it be possible to make a communication between android (bluetooth) and pc (non bluetooth) using the above two important things?

My purpose is that...
I'm intended to test my bluetooth transfer (android) to the pc....

Comment: Do you want to communicate via bluetooth with a Pc which has no bluetooth?

Comment: As far as my knowledge reaches I think that isn't possible. You need a way to transfer the data. Is like if you have a real address to send a letter but there is no postal company to deliver it. Even if your computer has no bluetooth, you could buy a bluetooth dongle. Take a look at this, one fellow of my job uses this to have bluetooth on it's PC: http://bluecove.org/